# Do I need Fantom Tether Interface for ROV

Tags: communication

I try to make a ROV for some undergraduate science project.I planing to use  raspberrypi for control and image processing but ı will use ethernet cable for cominication. But every source ı look they say I need to use a tether interface board(fathom series mostly) my question is do I really need a tether interface cause I dont actually know why ı need a tether interface while ı can simply connect my raspberrypi to my computer with a ethernet cable.

Comment: May I ask what ROV is?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remotely_operated_underwater_vehicle